# OR condition in wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make OR  condition in wordpress.But it not show any effect on query produce by WP_Query($args) I am very new to wordpress so i have not any idea of flow of wordpress query.

```
 if ( $params ) {
            extract($params);
            $args['meta_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'OR'
            );
            if (isset( $keywords )) {
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_address',
                'meta_value' => $keywords,
                );
            }
            if (isset($type)) {
                if($type !== '' && $type !=='all' ){
                    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_item_type',
                    'meta_value' => $type,
                    );
                }
            }
            if (isset($number)) {
                $args['posts_per_page'] = $number;
            }


            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND'
            );

            if ( isset( $category ) ) {
                if($category !== '' && $category !=='all' ){
                    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-item-category',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => (int)$category
                    );
                }
            }

            if ( isset($location) ) {
                if($location !== '' && $location !=='all' ){
                    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-item-location',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => (int)$location
                    );
                }
            }

            if ( isset($tag) ) {
                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'listing-item-tag',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => (int)$tag
                );
            }

        }

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

When i show in $query->request it seems like this.

In $args I get

```
 Array
(
    [post_type] => listing-item
    [post_status] => publish
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [meta_key] => eltd_listing_address
                    [meta_value] => Carrer de la Princesa, 24-26, 08003 Barcelona, Spain
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [meta_key] => eltd_listing_item_type
                    [meta_value] => 277
                )

        )

    [posts_per_page] => 12
)




 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing-item' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

Here i am not getting the OR condition.

I have not idea how to do in wordpress. any solution will highly appreciated.

Comment: `print_r` your `$args` variable and see if it holds the information you think it holds.

Comment: In $args it holds all the value that i want to do with queries but it not show in query and i am not getting desired data

Comment: Can you add that output to your post?

Comment: Array
(
    [post_type] => listing-item
    [post_status] => publish
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [meta_key] => eltd_listing_address
                    [meta_value] => Carrer de la Princesa, 24-26, 08003 Barcelona, Spain
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [meta_key] => eltd_listing_item_type
                    [meta_value] => 277
                )

        )

    [posts_per_page] => 12
) this is what i get from $args

Comment: ehm to your post, not as a comment. Can you correct it?

Comment: check this link and see if your format is correct https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a compare argument for your meta query for each key... so

```
        if (isset( $keywords )) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_address',
            'meta_value' => $keywords,
            );
        }
        if (isset($type)) {
            if($type !== '' && $type !=='all' ){
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_item_type',
                'meta_value' => $type,
                );
            }
        }
```

Becomes

```
        if (isset( $keywords )) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_address',
            'meta_value' => $keywords,
            'compare' => '=',
            );
        }
        if (isset($type)) {
            if($type !== '' && $type !=='all' ){
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'meta_key' => 'eltd_listing_item_type',
                'meta_value' => $type,
                'compare' => '=',
                );
            }
        }
```